# Reuse Bitrise step without developing custom one

Tags: bitrise

Is there any way to reuse step across Bitrise workflows? For example, let's say I have `script` step with bunch of shell script in it. I do not want to create my "own" full-grown step. The script is changing something in codebase and the changes will further be used by other steps of given workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use it across many apps the best solution is to convert it to a step - if you already have it as a script it's really simple using the `bitrise` CLI (`bitrise :step create`). That way you can version it and you can manage when a given workflow is updated to the new version.

If you don't want to do that, you can use the `Remote Bash Script Runner` https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/remote-script-runner step to run your script from a URL (e.g. from a secret GitHub Gist).

Alternatively you can also include your script in your repository, and then run that from a `Script` step or via the `Script Runner` step (https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/script-runner).

There's also an **unofficial** step to run a script from a private github repo: https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/github-script-runner

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. Ended up using https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/script-runner

Comment: Glad to hear @ror :)